# How to make Font Awesome icons responsive with all screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, font-awesome, screen-size

I want to use Font Awesome Icons in my Android app and I'm afraid of that Font Awesome icons won't be responsive with all screen sizes . So how to make them be fit and responsive for all screen sizes

Here is an example of my Icon text

in `activity_main.xml`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="&#xf004;"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:id="@+id/tvIcon1"
        android:textSize="500sp"
        />
```

in `MainActivity`

```
 Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.fa_regular_400);
       
        tvIcon1.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use library for responsive font or imageview or button etc for sdp library or ssp library in your gradle file which reduce your problem about it. then you can use anywhere in your project.

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

import these library in dependencies folder
then it will automatically popup their name as like @dimen/_16sdp etc

Comment: Please can you be more clear cause I can't get your answer

Comment: your issue is you use textsize=50sp , but it look small when it go big screen ?am i right

Comment: Okay you are right . I want to make its size be responsive with all screen sizes

Comment: I will try it and test in in different screen sizes and I will comment to you what happened with me and I hope it is the right way

Comment: are you import these libraries or not?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp     check this link it will resolve your issue

Comment: I'm going to import them now

Comment: I want to know what is the difference between sdp,ssp and can I use it with any view ?

Comment: SDP uses all type button size, textview size, etc, ssp used on text increase size. it means  i.e  textsize= @dimen/_16ssp, and button size  layout_height or width=@dimen/_16sdp etc .